# How to create a table from the aggregate() function in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
Type    Date    Lively  Count
sm      1/13/2010   10  10
sm      1/14/2010   10  20
sm      2/15/2010   20  30
am      4/16/2010   5   42
am      1/17/2010   10  34
am      3/18/2010   40  54
sm      1/19/2010   10  65
sm      4/20/2010   5   67
sm      3/21/2010   40  76
```

I'm trying to average out all the numeric parameters by month. So my resultant data set would ideally be:

```
Date     Lively Count
Jan 2010     10     32.25
Feb 2010     20     30.00
Mar 2010     40     65.00
Apr 2010      5     54.50
```

I'm very close to this, what I currently have is:

```
         Lively Count
Jan 2010     10     32.25
Feb 2010     20     30.00
Mar 2010     40     65.00
Apr 2010      5     54.50
```

As you can see I'm missing the title 'Date'. Here is my code:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(data[3:4], as.Date(data[,2], "%m/%d/%Y"))
aggregate(z, as.yearmon, mean)
```

I don't know how to make a title for the left column ('Date'), and more importantly, I don't know how to make the output of aggregate() into a table (resultant data set).

Comment: The leftmost "column" is not a column, but the `index` for your `zoo` object. Like `rownames` in base R for a `data.table`, that's not a "column" so you can't give it a name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `list` format to specify your names within `aggregate`.

To get your "date" values, you need to refer to the "index" of your zoo object

```
aggregate(list(Lively = z[, "Lively"], Count = z[, "Count"]), 
          list(Date = as.yearmon(index(z))), mean)
#       Date Lively Count
# 1 Jan 2010     10 32.25
# 2 Feb 2010     20 30.00
# 3 Mar 2010     40 65.00
# 4 Apr 2010      5 54.50
```

Alternatively, you can easily change your names if required. This will allow you to be able to use the much nicer formula method for `aggregate`.

```
x <- aggregate(. ~ as.yearmon(index(z)), z, mean)
names(x)[1] <- "Date"
x
#       Date Lively Count
# 1 Jan 2010     10 32.25
# 2 Feb 2010     20 30.00
# 3 Mar 2010     40 65.00
# 4 Apr 2010      5 54.50
```

---

Note, however, that by doing so, you miss out on all the goodness that `zoo` has to offer by doing this. You've essentially taken a `data.frame`, converted it to a `zoo` object, and re-converted it to a `data.frame`.

Your `aggregate(z, as.yearmon, mean)` solution would be the way I would go about it, and refer to the date by using `index()`.

---

### Update

If you're just doing this at a later stage for aesthetic reasons, you can keep working with `zoo` objects since it will give you a lot of flexibility that you might not get with base R functions, and then use `cbind` at the end.

Following from where you left off:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(data[3:4], as.Date(data[,2], "%m/%d/%Y"))
x <- aggregate(z, as.yearmon, mean)
cbind(Date = index(x), 
      as.data.frame.matrix(x, row.names = NULL))
#       Date Lively Count
# 1 Jan 2010     10 32.25
# 5 Feb 2010     20 30.00
# 6 Mar 2010     40 65.00
# 8 Apr 2010      5 54.50
```

Comment: @SimonO101, I didn't post for `as.yearmon`, but because the OP is trying to get the results from a `zoo` object. Pretty minor difference, I guess.

Comment: Still, I didn't know it, and I immediately have a use for it. So I am trying to say THANKS! :-)

Comment: i also found a nice method called fortify() that converts a zoo object into a data frame http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/autoplot.zoo

Comment: @user2649452, sure. You can also use `data.frame(Date = index(x), coredata(x))`. I'm still not clear why you don't want a `data.frame` (unless this is the final stage and you're just doing it for aesthetic reasons). `zoo` would most likely be faster for many things because operations on matrices are usually much faster in R than operations on `data.frame`s.